# What is a DLL's "image version" used for (set with the /VERSION Visual C++ linker switch)?

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I've read the documentation for the Visual C++ /VERSION linker switch ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h88b7dc8.aspx ) and I understand that this value is shown as the "image version" when you use "dumpbin /headers", but it is not clear to me why you would set the "image version" or what happens if you don't set it and use the default value of "0.0".

Could someone explain to me why you might set the "image version"? Is this value now obsolete?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this, as the uninstaller I'm working on always results in PCA being displayed on vista when the uninstall is cancelled at any point (when UAC is off, and only when uninstall is done through appwiz.cpl) and the only way I have been able to fix it is to set the image version in the .exe header to 6.0. I would like to know more about the repercussions of this.

Comment: @David That is interesting. That at least suggests that the "image version" is actually used for something.

Could you vote up this question using the up arrow next to the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best explanation I could find: http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/version_numbers.htm

> **IMAGE VERSION** This value is set by the developer of the module by using the VERSION statement in their DEF file or by using the /VERSION linker option. It usually represents the version of the module or product that the module is part of, but can contain any value since it is up to the developer to set it. If the developer does not specify a version, then this value will default to 0.0. *This value may be used as a last resort when comparing two modules to check which module is newer.*

The last sentence seems to imply this is used as a last check when loading DLLs (when your EXE binds a specific DLL version). That seems to align with the behavior that was seen with Vista's Program Compatibility Assistant (PCA) mentioned in the comment above.